# Show element that is pointerpressed

Tags: c#, uwp

In UWP, I would like to know how to show in a textbox/block which element has been pressed by the user. for example, if I have a rectangle with event handler pointer pressed, how do I show that it is a " rectangle " that has been pressed by the user?

Comment: In the event handler write ``textBox1.Text = sender.GetType().Name;``

Comment: As the upper comment says you have `sender` - the element that was pressed.

Comment: @RandRandom Thanks, that worked

Comment: Made, an answer pls accept it, if that was sufficient for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the event handler write `textBox1.Text = sender.GetType().Name;`